# Problema con funciones, laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Realizo un proyecto, y necesito cambiar algunos parámetros de la función que se llama al register.

Encontre las rutas del register en el siguiente: Vendor > Laravel > Framework > src > Illuminate > Routing > Router.php

Aquí el código de la función completa:

```
    public function auth(array $options = [])
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('admin/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    if ($options['register'] ?? true) {
        $this->get('admin/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
        $this->post('admin/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
    }

    // Password Reset Routes...
    if ($options['reset'] ?? true) {
        $this->resetPassword();
    }

    // Email Verification Routes...
    if ($options['verify'] ?? false) {
        $this->emailVerification();
    }
}
```

El problema llega cuando me voy a la carpeta App > Constrollers > Auth > RegisterController.php y no me sale la función showRegistrationFrom

Aquí código del RegisterController.php

```
use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/admin/inicio';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{

    return User::create([
        'role' => 'helper',
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'nick' => 'default',
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

}

¿Donde deberían estar esas funciones que se reflejan al especificar la ruta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los métodos de Auth de Laravel, vienen definidos en la clase que extienden, lo cual quiere decir que puedes sobrescribir los métodos aunque no aparezcan ahí.

[Aquí](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.html#method_showRegistrationForm) puedes encontrar la clase de donde viene showRegistratiónForm.

PD: No deberías cambiar directamente los métodos en las clases, simplemente crea el método en el controlador y añade funcionalidad o sobrescribe el método.